# google places autocomplete iOS search after x characters

Tags: ios, autocomplete, google-places-api

Is there a way to run google place iOS api autocomplete prediction after x characters have been entered in search bar? I am using *GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController*. It just triggers prediction after one character has been entered in search bar.

Comment: You can implement your own controller and call autocomplete api whenever you wish. Check implementation of Get place predictions programmatically  in this link : https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

Comment: @Priyal I have already read that link. I was hoping I don't have to implement my own controller but use google provided autocomplete UI control, I used this code  
`var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
  var searchController: UISearchController?  
resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()  
SearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)  
searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController`

Comment: @DawoodGul any solution?